# query regarding pdf's cross reference table

Tags: pdf

I was having some doubts over pdf's cross reference table. As I know that whenever we changed some existing objects(eg images,text etc) in pdf and then after saving, new cross reference table is generated. Now my question is that for updated objects it can access data from new table but for non changed objects does it query the prev xref table(the address it can get from trailer /Prev).

Answer (score 1):

To look up an object you have to check all cross references tables, starting with the newest. Please read [the PDF reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).